# Div doesn't center when min-width set

Tags: html, center, css

I want a webpage, with the content centered, and specify a minimum width so it resizes on small screens of smartphones, but still looks fine on PCs.

If I set the width of my div to 1024px, and margins auto, then the div stays centered when the browser window is stretched wider than that.

But obviously this requires the user to scroll sideways if they're viewing the site on a small screen.

So I tried changing width to "min-width:480px" and the div does not stay centered in a large browser window.

I've done lots of googling and the blog/forum posts for this very topic claim that all you have to do is set min-width and auto margins.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    *
    {
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
    }
    #content
    {
      margin: 0px auto;
      min-width: 480px;
      background:#BBB;
      height:800px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <span>content</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

At this stage I'm only testing in Chrome.

Comment: Have you considered media queries?

Comment: Are you trying to make this responsive? Because setting the width of the div to a specific pixel value is NOT. You want to set the width to a percentage (100%?), so it will continue to scale down with the browser until it hits the min-width. And just a quick note...480px is still a bit wider than most popular smartphones (portrait), so horizontal scrolling is still going to occur in portrait mode.

Comment: min-width will only ensure that the div does not get smaller than that width.  If the window goes smaller than that width, the extra margins should be gone and the div should be centered.  So, I'm not quite sure which part you are trying to center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

min-width will kick in as the div is told to be *smaller* than the min-width value. If you set the width of the div to be `width: 1024px;`, then it will always be `1024px`. However, if you set it to a percentage value (ie. 100%, 93.75%, etc), it will scale down, and the min-width value will kick in once `100% < min-width`. So set the width of the div to be a percentage value, and you should be good to go.

Also, I'm not a huge fan of wrapping all of my content in a single, all-encompassing *content* div. Maybe I'm just picky, but IMHO, thats what the `<body></body>` element is for. And you can add `margin: 0 auto;` to just the `Body` element, and that will center the everything relative to the browser. Then the margins of the specific elements from there is up to you. Anyways, food for thought.

Answer (score 4):

That's because `min-width` is a constraint and not a width declaration. Auto centering using `margin:0 auto` only takes a width declaration to work. One suggestion would be to just define a width for your `#content` area and add a `@media` query for mobile devices with a width of 100%.

e.g.

```
#content { width:960px; }

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    #content {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: or `#content { width: 93.75%; }`...so no matter what size the screen (mobile, desktop, 146" monitor, etc.), it will scale responsively :)

Comment: @JordanForeman depending on the application or design, that can work as well. Though he wants to center the content area as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, min-width will make your div 480px wide on small screens - it means that if the screen is smaller that 480px, your div won't fit.

The thing is, div is a block element so if you won't specify the width, it will stretch to be as wide as the parent element.

I would suggest to look into [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified a fixed `width` for your content container so by default it's going to take up the full width of it's parent.

And you can't set a `min-width` if you have a fixed `width`.

Typically, you'd have a separate CSS sheet just for mobile devices and use a media query.

Comment: I did not know about media queries. Thank you all who suggested it.