# Center content when window is wide enough

Tags: css

A lot of websites use the technique where the page is a minimum width, and if the browser goes wider than this then the content is centered. A perfect example if this Facebook, if you open up http://www.facebook.com and drag the browser window to its minimum width, then slowly drag it out until the window is as wide as the screen allows it to be. You'll notice that the page's content remains the same size but keeps centered when it has room to. How is this achieved?

Comment: media queries | Responsive design

Comment: You may be able to figure out the answer to your question by looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827330/div-doesnt-center-when-min-width-set . Or look at the source code of the facebook page.

Answer (score 2):

You can as well just set a width or evena  max-width:

```
#maincontainer {
width:90%; /* to show it can have width + max-width */
max-width:1020px;
margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: I ended up finding a solution that uses min-width combined with margins, check out the jsFiddle I posted

Answer (score 1):

this reminds me about the grid system.

anyway, hopefully I get what you're asking here.. from my point, basically all you need to do is just define the content's `width` and set the `margin` (left and right) to 'auto'. here is what I always do when designing a web page.

### CSS

```
.pgheader, .pgbody, .pgfooter {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
}
.pageWrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px; /* this if you go with fixed sized */

    /*** if you want to go with dynamic width (either min- or max-width),
         you can go with the following

    width: 90%;
    min-width: 960px;

    ***/
}
```

### HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="pgheader">
        <div class="pageWrapper">
            ... content goes here ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pgbody">
        <div class="pageWrapper">
            ... content goes here ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pgfooter">
        <div class="pageWrapper">
            ... content goes here ...
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS media queries. Give http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ a read, it's a great introduction to it.

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't find what I was looking for here, I played with some css properties and eventually got what I wanted. It basically combines two wrappers together to keep centered horizontally while also maintaining a margin on either side, and a min-with on the body itself. I put together a jsFiddle to show how it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/eDWKw/

```
<body>
    <div class="margin-wrapper">
       <div class="centered-wrapper">
            content
       </div>
    <div>
</body>


body{
    min-width:400px;
}
.margin-wrapper{
    margin-right:80px;
    margin-left:80px;
}
.centered-wrapper{
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```